# printing formatted list items on the same line in python

Tags: python, function, string-formatting

I am a beginner programmer working through one of the final projects on freecodecamp.

I am using Mac OS python3.10

The problem requests that we create a funciton that takes a list of horizontally arranged arithmetic problems as an argument and rearranges them vertically.

This is the function call:

```
arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

And this is the desired outcome:

```
   32      3801      45      123
+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49
-----    ------    ----    -----
```

I was able to reformat the equations vertically but I got stuck trying to figure out how to print them side by side on the same line. Here is the code I wrote.

```
def aa(problem) :
    for i in problem[:] :
        problem.remove(i)
        p = i.split()
        # print(p)
        ve = '\t{:>5}\n\t{:<1}{:>4}\n\t-----'.format(p[0],p[1],p[2])
        print(ve)

    return

aa(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

And here is the outcome of that code.

```
   32
+ 698
-----
 3801
-   2
-----
   45
+  43
-----
  123
+  49
-----
```

I have already tried using print(*variable) and ' '.join. When i try those solutions I get this.

```
       3 2
 +   6 9 8
 - - - - -
   3 8 0 1
 -       2
 - - - - -
       4 5
 +     4 3
 - - - - -
     1 2 3
 +     4 9
 - - - - -
```

I appreciate you taking the time to read my problem, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: Build up a list of lists like `[['32','+','698'], ['3801','-','2'], ...]`. Then format and print the first element of each list.  Next format and print the 2nd/3rd elements of each list.  Finally print the dashes.

Comment: I actually tried something very similar. I should have posted it. I put the list within another list like you said : [['32', '+', '698'], ['3801', '-', '2'], ['45', '+', '43'], ['123', '+', '49']]. And I tried to iterate through it with a for loop that formatted all of the elements in the list. But I ended up with the exact same outcome. But you're suggesting to print them all separately without iterating through the list?

Comment: Format *all* the first elements and print them in one line, then format all the 2nd/3rd elements and them them in one line.  I have a solution that prints exactly your desired outcome, including varying widths of dashes, but you should make an attempt yourself to learn more.

Comment: I agree. I'll take a crack at this tomorrow using your hint, thanks.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I figured it out using your hint. I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that exactly matches the desired outcome.  It determines the widths of each equation:

```py
def arithmetic_arranger(equations):
    # Parse to list of lists, e.g.:
    #   [['32', '+', '698'], ['3801', '-', '2'], ['45', '+', '43'], ['123', '+', '49']]
    parsed = [equation.split() for equation in equations]

    # For each sublist, determine the widest string and build a list of those widths, e.g.:
    #   [3, 4, 2, 3]
    widths = [len(max(items,key=len)) for items in parsed]

    # zip() matches each width with each parsed sublist.
    # Print the first operands right-justified with appropriate widths.
    print('   '.join([f'  {a:>{w}}' for w,(a,op,b) in zip(widths,parsed)]))

    # Print the operator and the second operand.
    print('   '.join([f'{op} {b:>{w}}' for w,(a,op,b) in zip(widths,parsed)]))

    # Print the dashed lines under each equation.
    print('   '.join(['-'*(w+2) for w in widths]))

arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

Output:

```
   32     3801     45     123
+ 698   -    2   + 43   +  49
-----   ------   ----   -----
```

Comment: I like this solution. The code you are assigning to the "parsed" variable is interesting. I didn't know you could use the 'for' keyword like that. Also, I like that there is the appropriate amount of dashes under the 45 + 43.

Comment: @JonGuinn Actually the `parsed =` line could be more simple.  Guess I wasn't thinking at the time :)  Updated.

Comment: That is much simpler to read. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

when you print a character to the terminal the cursor position moves forward. When you print a newline the cursor goes one position down. You'd have to manually bring it up again to print in the above line. You could use [ANSI Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to control the position of the cursor. It's a lot more hard and complex.

You achieve the desired output by changing how to represent the equation. Store each of the equations as `[operand1, sign, operand2]`. Now, simply print all operand1 in a single line. print sign and operand 2 next. Then print `-----`.

```
def fmt(lst):
    op1, sign, op2 = zip(*map(str.split, lst))
    line1  = "\t".join([f"{op:>5}" for op in op1])
    line2  = "\t".join([f"{s:<1}{op:>4}" for s, op in zip(sign, op2)])
    line3  = "-----\t"*len(lst)
    print("\n".join([line1, line2, line3])

fmt(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

Output:

```
   32    3801      45     123
+ 698   -   2   +  43   +  49
-----   -----   -----   -----
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who have taken the time to help. I came up with a solution using the hint from @MarkTolonen who suggested I put a list within a list. Below is my solution. Let me know if there is a way to do this that is more elegant.

Function:

```
def aa(problem) :
    new_list = list()
    for i in problem[:] :
        problem.remove(i)
        p = i.split()
        new_list.append(p)
    print(new_list)
    for l in new_list :
        l1 = '{:>5}'.format(l[:][0])
        print(l1,end='   ')
    print('')
    for l in new_list:
        l2 = '{:<1}{:>4}'.format(l[:][1],l[:][2])
        print(l2,end='   ')
    print('')
    for l in new_list:
        print('-----',end='   ')

    return
```

Function call:

```
aa(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

Outcome:

```
   32    3801      45     123
+ 698   -   2   +  43   +  49
-----   -----   -----   -----   %
```

Also. what does the '%' mean at the end of the printed dashes?

Comment: Not sure where the % comes from. Your final print doesn’t end with a new line due to the `end` override, so it could be your shell prompt.